# how i can fix the errors of migrate command

Tags: python, django, django-models

i'm new in django 
i want to create a  businessplan application 
i create 3 classes in my models file "models.py"
when i run python manage.py migrates
it show me this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", 
line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 
328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 
 369, in execute
     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 
83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 89, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 
295, in check_consistent_history
    raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied 
before its dependency businessplan.0001_initial on database 'de
fault'.
```

this is my models.py :
it contain 4 classes Entrepreneur ,Admin , User(abstract) and projet:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import *
#user
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type=((1,"admin"),(2,"staff"))
    user_type=models.CharField(default=1,choices=user_type,max_length=10)

# Entrepreneur
class Entrepreneur(models.Model):
    id_models= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nom_et_prenom=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_naissance=models.DateField()
    adresse_entr=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    telephone=models.IntegerField()
    statut_social=(('ce','celébataire'),
                   ('ma','marié'),
                   ('di','divorcé'),
                   ('ve','veuf'),
                   )
    occupation=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    niveau_scolaire=(
        ('pri','primaire'),
        ('sec','secondaire'),
        ('cap','certificat aptitude professionel'),
        ('btp','brevet technicien professionel'),
        ('bts','brevet technicien superieur'),
        ('lic','license'),
        ('mai','maitrise'),
        ('mas','mastere'),
        ('doc','doctorat'),
                    )
    niveau_scolaire=models.CharField(default='ser',choices=niveau_scolaire,max_length=50)
    annnee_exp=models.IntegerField()
    email=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255)
#Projet
class Projet(models.Model):
    id_models=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nom_projet=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lieu_implantation=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type_projet=(
        ('ser','service'),
        ('com','commerce'),
        ('agr','agricuture'),
        ('ind','industrie'),
        ('IT','technologie information'),
        ('art','artisanat'),
        ('tor','tourisme'),
    )
    type_projet=models.CharField(default='ser',choices=type_projet,max_length=50)
    produit=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id_promoteur=models.ForeignKey(Entrepreneur,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#admin
class Admin(models.Model):
    id_admin=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    objects=models.Manager()
```

first i run makemigration command and everythings is ok 
but when i run migrate command it's not ok

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete the migration files under the migrations folder of the app excluding the **init** file.If this will not work then do the same process and delete rows related to that app in django migrartions table. Then try to migrate. It will work. Happy CODING :D

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the database then migration files, then make migrations and migrate to have a new consistent database. Don't forget to store any valuable data you have in the database.

Answer (score 0):

- solution is that delete all migration file from app/migrations folder.
- hit python3 manage.py makemigration
- It's create fresh migration file